# Python console code with minted

Tags: color, minted, sourcecode

I am using `minted` to highlight source code in my document.

I have defined

```
\definecolor{codeyellow}{RGB}{255,251,204}
\newminted{python}{linenos,breaklines,frame=lines,bgcolor=codeyellow}
```

in the preamble.

But I will also be able to show console code and output. I have read that I can use `pycon` so I have tried

```
\newminted{pycon}{linenos,breaklines,frame=lines}
```

but it shows just a listing with white background and black text. I know I should probably set `bgcolor` etc. but can I find a theme which suits the 'normal' console output look/theme?

## Edit (minimal working solution)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted{pycon}{%
    linenos,
    breaklines,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    frame=lines,
    tabsize=4
}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\begin{pyconcode}
python manage.py runserver:8000
\end{pyconcode}
\caption{Console}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question with a MWE :-)